# Polyfills in Gatsby.js - String.prototype.matchAll

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, gatsby

I'm having trouble polyfilling `String.prototype.matchAll` in Gatsby.js, which is using Webpack to bundle.  Based on my understanding of the  [Gatsby Browser Support documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/browser-support/), I thought that this should be done by default, since `@babel/preset-env` is used under the hood.  After further investigation, it looks like the version of `core-js` that `@babel/preset-env` is using is `2`.  I tried to update the `.babelrc` file (shown below) to include separate configuration of the preset where I could update the version, but received errors.  When trying to build with the new config, I received an error in every place there was an attempted polyfill (shown below).

```
    {
      "presets": [
        [
          "babel-preset-gatsby",
          {
            "targets": {
              "browsers": [">0.25%", "not dead"]
            }
          }
        ],
        [
          "@babel/preset-env",
          {
            "targets": {
              "browsers": [">0.25%", "not dead"]
            },
            "corejs": "3.6"
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
```

```
ERROR #98123  WEBPACK
Generating JavaScript bundles failed
Can't resolve 'core-js/modules/web.dom-collections.iterator' in 'C:\Users\xxxx\OneDrive\Desktop\directory-frontend-gatsby\src\components'

ERROR #98123  WEBPACK
Generating JavaScript bundles failed
Can't resolve 'core-js/modules/web.dom-collections.for-each' 'C:\Users\xxxx\OneDrive\Desktop\directory-frontend-gatsby\src\components'

etc...
```

I should mention that I'm using the newest version of `core-js`, `@babel/preset-env`, and `@babel/core`.

```
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.5",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4"
```

Also, I thought that it might have been an issue with running this on Windows, since paths are constructed using \ instead of /, but also attempted the build on Ubuntu and received the same output.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't polyfilled in production build? How did you verify?
The default browserlist used by Gatsby should indeed polyfill this.

As for `core-js`, there is an [open issue](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/15601) for the upgrade which isn't that easy and will involve breaking changes.

Comment: I used a cross browser testing tool to load versions of different browsers that lack support.  On those browsers, the site crashed in the areas that attempted to utilize that method and after opening the console, I could see that the method was said to not be a function of the object that it was called on.  Since I don't have much time, I decided to replace the instances of matchAll with the polyfill suggested by MDN.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the issue.